# How to put some validation on Qwizard finish button slot and get confirmation before qwizard finishing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwizard

I try to put some validations on user inputs and display a summery of entered information and get confirm from user if all thing is right. I think i need to modify the slot of QWizard FinishButton but i cannot find the main slot.

I try this way but wizard is immediately closed on finish clicking.

```
self.button(QtWidgets.QWizard.FinishButton).clicked.connect(self.do_something)

def do_something():
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate after pressing the "Finish" button then you must disconnect the clicked signal from the associated slots (such as the [accept()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) slot), connect it to the new slot and if it is valid to call the [accept()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) function:

```py
    # ...
    finish_button = self.button(QtWidgets.QWizard.FinishButton)
    finish_button.disconnect()
    finish_button.clicked.connect(self.finish_validate)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def finish_validate(self):
    button = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Validation", "Is valid?")
    if button == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.accept()
```